# Create new tables in Coldfusion ORM

Tags: database, orm, coldfusion

I'm pretty new to Object Relational Mappings and, in general, to Coldfusion. I'm developing an application that will use a different table for each user, so is there a way to generate new ones every time a user registers (without using ORMReload() or restarting the whole Coldfusion service)?

Alternatively, since I don't need any complex relationship for my tables, should I use old-fashioned cfquerys, or do I get better performance by using ORM to read and update my database?

Comment: Why do you need separate tables per user? What do they store?

Comment: That certainly doesn't sound like it will scale. How will you manage when there are 10,000 user accounts?

Comment: It's a social-network based site, each user needs to have a list with his "friends".

Comment: Sounds like you want to create 2 tables. A "users" table with a unique user_id field, and a "friends" table with a foreign key to users. . You basically need to normalize your data to avoid one table per user.

Answer (score 3):

The first step of the "solution" here is for you to read up on how databases work.

Your question - as observed by the comments attached to it - demonstrates that you've got a fundamental gap in your understanding of how to approach this problem; and the gap is sufficiently broad as to not be the sort of thing a Q&A website like this is suited for.

I don't mean this to sound blunt (or unhelpful!), sorry.

Comment: Don't worry, you're right. This is the first time I'm doing a dynamic website, and since I'm self-tought, I guess it's normal to miss some fundamental concept. I'll look into this foreign-keys thing. However, I'm still interested in my question: can I create new tables with orm, without restarting it? And is it better then cfquerys about the performance?